# REST API to download large sized files in JAVA 8 without running into timeout

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, java-8, download

I have client and server side apps which are designed to have a session no longer than 30 seconds.

I am writing a rest api to download reports which sometimes contains really large amount of data but it's running into timeouts. Is there any better way to do this so it doesn't exceed time limit of 30 seconds?

Here is the controller at server side:

```
@GetMapping("/download")
public void downloadReport() {
    List<Person> people = getPeople(); // data retrieval logic
    
    response.addHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
    response.addHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, 
    
    MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE);

    for (String person : people) {
        StreamUtils.copy(new ByteArrayInputStream(person.concat("\n").getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)), 
   response.getOutputStream());
    }
    response.flushBuffer();
}
```

Here is the code on client side:

```
@GetMapping("/download")
public void downloadReport(@RequestParam MultiValueMap<String, String> downloadRequest, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    ResponseEntity<byte[]> result = restClient.downloadReport(URI, downloadRequest);
    if (result.getStatusCode().equals(HttpStatus.OK)) {
        String fileName = result.getHeaders().getContentDisposition().getFilename();
        response.addHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
        response.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
        StreamUtils.copy(result.getBody(), response.getOutputStream());
        response.flushBuffer();
    } else {
        throw new Exception("Could not download report.");
    }
}
```

Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the problem is in your code? Is the download speed slower than you'd expect? Or is the file just too large to be downloaded in under 30 seconds? Because if that's the case, you'll either have to break the file up into smaller parts or disable/enlarge the timeout for download endpoints.

Comment: did you try flushing after each person?

Comment: The best way to handle "Downloading context" is to use "Websockets".

Comment: @JonathanJOhx why? http is perfectly capable of handling very long downloads without issue. it's just a matter of letting the client know that you still have stuff to send

Comment: @AMagic, you have an api that calls an api, gets the response, and sends it to its own client? isn't that what a proxy does?

Comment: @njzk2 Using Websockets for Long Downloads: 
Real-time Updates > Websockets are ideal when you need real-time updates during the download process. With Websockets, the server can send data to the client as soon as it's available, allowing for a more interactive and real-time experience. 
Bidirectional Communication > Websockets allow bidirectional communication, meaning the client can also send data or control messages to the server, which is useful for more interactive applications.

Comment: @Jorn Breaking the files is a good idea but isn't an option. My guess is that it's taking longer in `StreamUtils.copy` on both client and server side. There could be some way to make it faster?

Comment: You haven't shown where `StreamUtils` is coming from (Apache?), but I doubt there's a bottleneck there. Copying one stream to another is very much a solved problem, and if you're using a big library, I wouldn't assume it's the bottleneck. However, using the `ByteArrayInputStream` is a lot of unneccessary overhead. You'd be better off writing to the output stream directly.

Comment: You could also open a normal `java.net.ServerSocket`, get its local port, then forward the client to that port, or in any other way confer the message of the new port to the client. Maybe even use a `java.net.Socket` in the client. This way you could use the o-so-much-better raw Sockets instead of HTTP, maybe even use `ZipOutputStream`, and have no more timeouts to worry about. The big and ugly downside is how to handle firewalls and proxies and other routing interference...

Comment: But it looks like the real problem in your code lies with you handling all that String data, wrapping all that up in a huge array (check your systems swap file activity!), and only once it's all there, then write it to the `OutputStream`. Maybe try writing every line that `person` has onto the stream directly. Maybe also `flush()` afterwards, if there's a lot of time between the last write and getting the next person ready... And another problem  is that the server does not send how much data it actually sends, so maybe the client is waiting for more. Try closing the connection after sending.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's one optimization you can easily do. Writing to a `ByteArrayInputStream` first, then copying that to the `OutputStream` is not needed.

```
@GetMapping("/download")
public void downloadReport() {
    List<Person> people = getPeople(); // data retrieval logic
    
    response.addHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
    response.addHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, 
    
    MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE);

    try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(response.getOutputStream(), false, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
        for (String person : people) {
            writer.write(person);
            writer.write("\n");
        }
        response.flushBuffer();
    }
}
```